# Assigning widths to string fields using writeOGR() from rgdal?

Tags: r, mapinfo, rgdal

I am currently working with MapInfo files in the `.tab` format. I am using R (3.1.0 for Windows) to read and write files in this format, however, I am encountering an issue with `writeOGR()` from the `rgdal` package. When I write a MapInfo file in the `.tab` format, all the string fields are being assigned a width of 254 characters. This is very problematic for larger datasets with numerous string fields, as it dramatically increases the size of the output `.dat` file.

Below is an example:

```
require(rgdal)
shape <- readOGR(dsn = directory, layer = "Up")
writeOGR(obj = shape, dsn = directory, layer = "Up2", driver = "MapInfo File")
```

Here's an excerpt from the original `Up.tab` file:

```
!table
!version 300
!charset WindowsLatin1

Definition Table
  Type NATIVE Charset "WindowsLatin1"
  Fields 52
    ID Integer Index 1 ;
    unid_planejamento Char (4) ;
    codigo2 Char (4) ;
    descricao Char (100) ;
```

And one from my modified `Up2.tab` file:

```
!table
!version 300
!charset Neutral

Definition Table
  Type NATIVE Charset "Neutral"
  Fields 52
    ID Integer ;
    unid_planejamento Char (254) ;
    codigo2 Char (254) ;
    descricao Char (254) ;
```

Note that all the string fields have now been assigned a width of 254 characters. I should also note that the `.dat` file has gone from 43KB to 93KB.

I understand there are some [creation issues](http://www.gdal.org/drv_mitab.html) when writing MapInfo files, however, it is not clear to me whether or not this can be resolved by somehow controlling the string field width.

I have searched for ways to do so using `dataset_options` and `layer_options`, but have not been successful.

Is there a way of controlling the string field width using `writeOGR()`? And if not, is there a way of using R to write a new `.dat` file (from my understanding, this is a dBase III DBF file) with the appropriate string widths?

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar issue using writeOGR() and the default setting of character fields to 80 characters.  To get around this you can use layers options in the writeOGR parameters, specifically

```
layer_options = "RESIZE=YES"
```

This will dynamically resize character fields to appropriate size rather than giving the full default allotment of characters.